# Hausdorff space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

we know that  each infinite subspace of a KC space contain an infinite discrete subspace

The Hausdorff spaces imply KC spaces.But:

**Is it right to say that every Hausdorff space has an infinite discrete subspace?**

Comment: Any finite discrete space is Hausdorff, but obviously can't contain an infinite discrete subspace.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* true that every *infinite* Hausdorff space $X$ has an infinite discrete (in itself) subspace. The extra condition that $X$ is infinite itself is clearly necessary...
And if you know the fact for KC spaces, it certainly follows for Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: I want to see exact proof  for Hausdorff space, please tell me  which book show it? Thanks.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/186791/4280 has a proof.